# Тире в "с даты начала исследования — 1 марта 2018 г. — по дату окончания исследования — 10 апреля 2021 г., подтверждают..."

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> Данные, представленные в настоящем отчете, который охватывает период с даты начала исследования — 1 марта 2018 г. — по дату окончания исследования — 10 апреля 2021 г., подтверждают эффективность рассматриваемых лекарственных препаратов.

Правильно ли расставлены тире в этом предложении?

Answer (score 1):

Данные, представленные в настоящем отчете, который охватывает период с даты начала исследования (1 марта 2018 г.) по дату окончания исследования (10 апреля 2021 г.), подтверждают эффективность рассматриваемых лекарственных препаратов.

Иначе тире по разным основаниям будут рядом.

Comment: Правильно ли расставлены тире в оригинальном предложении?